# block incoming url (proxy)

Tags: php

I am trying to block people who use a proxy from attempting to view my site. I know its not a 100% solution to the problem but I want to stop anonymous web proxy from proxy.org.

I notice all urls eith start with website.com/search.php?u=fsd5f4s56df4 or browse.php/45sdf56sd4f How can I block people with this us the url and redirect them to google for example

Answer (score 0):

You can look at `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` though it's not 100% guaranteed

Comment: Some do, read the OP.  And even still, I did state it's not 100% guaranteed...nothing is 100% guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Gather (and keep up to date) all IP addresses used by the proxy you don't like and block those. As you say, there's no real way to identify proxies for sure. Also, proxies aren't bad in themselves and many of your visitor may *have to* use one, so you don't want to block all proxies outright.